# How to fix infinite run time when VVP start simulation?

Tags: verilog

this verilog code for Multiplier 4x4 have a serious problem when simulation starts using vvp.i am totally confused and can not understand where should i put an end statement that finish the simulation?

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
 module mult_4x4(
     input reset,start, 
     input[3:0] A,B, 
     output [7:0] O, output Finish
         );
reg [7:0] O;
wire Finish;  
wire Phi0,Phi1;// 2 phase clocking
wire m1,m2,m3,m4;
// state machine
reg[3:0] State;
// Accumulator
reg [8:0] ACC; // Accumulator
// logic to create 2 phase clocking when starting
nand u0(m1,start,m2);
buf #20 u1(m2,m1);
buf #10 u2(Phi0,m1);// First phase clocking
not #2 u5(m4,Phi0);
assign m3=~m1; 
and #2 u4(Phi1,m3,m4);// Second phase clocking
assign Finish = (State==9)? 1'b1:1'b0; // Finish Flag
// FSM
always @(posedge Phi0 or posedge Phi1 or posedge reset)
begin
if(reset) begin
State <= 0; 
ACC <= 0; 
O <= 0; 
end
 else if((Phi0==1'b1) || (Phi1==1'b1)) begin // 2 phase clocking
 if(State==0)
 begin
 ACC[8:4] <= 5'b00000; // begin cycle
 ACC[3:0] <= A; // Load A
 State <= 1;
 end
 else if(State==1 || State == 3 || State ==5 || State ==7) 
                // add/shift State
 begin
 if(ACC[0] == 1'b1) begin // add multiplicand
 ACC[8:4] <= {1'b0,ACC[7:4]} + B; 
 State <= State + 1;
 end
 else
 begin
 ACC <= {1'b0,ACC[8:1]};// shift right
 State <= State + 2;
 end
 end
 else if(State==2 || State == 4 || State ==6 || State ==8) 
                // shift State
 begin
 ACC <= {1'b0,ACC[8:1]}; // shift right
 State <= State + 1;
 end 
 else if(State == 9) begin
  State <= 0;
 O <= ACC[7:0]; 
 end
 end
 end 

endmodule

// TestBench
module test();
// signals
 reg start,reset;
 reg[3:0] A,B;
 // Outputs
 wire [7:0] O;
 wire Finish;
// device under test
mult_4x4 dut(reset,start, A,B,O,Finish);
initial begin
reset=1; // reset
#40 start = 0;A =14; B= 11;
#400 reset = 0; 
#40 start = 1; // start

end 

endmodule
```

after running this code,simulating never stop and when you press control+c (in cmd) it shows this message:
** VVP Stop(0) **
** Flushing output streams.
** Current simulation time is 56484472000 ticks.

Comment: The fact that you've tagged this "fpga" suggests you're actually wanting to make this. I doubt very much whether you could and wonder why you'd want to. What are you trying to do? I ask because if you took a convention approach, your problem would disappear. So why are you taking such an unconventional approach?

Comment: @MatthewTaylor i am trying to getting help from anyone to understand why simulating never stop!!!and where should i put a block of code to prevent this infinite ticks.although i want to present this code for my classmates but with this problem i can not getting the signals and waves with gtkwave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i forgot to add :

@(posedge finish);
$finish;

in the end of my code...